# Error uploading data into Teradata using Teradatasql module in python

Tags: python, teradata, teradatasql

I am trying to upload data into a table in Teradata using TeradataSQL module in python, but I am getting the following error:

```
A failure occurred while executing rows 1 through 2 of a batch request...Caused by [Version 17.0.0.8] [Session 21731976] [Teradata Database] [Error 3939] 
There is a mismatch between the number of parameters specified and the number of parameters required.
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import teradatasql

listbatch = x.values.tolist()

with teradatasql.connect ('{"host":"whomooz","user":"guest","password":"please"}') as con:
    with con.cursor () as cur:
        cur.executemany ("insert into mytableinTeradata  ('?,?,?')", listbatch)
```

This is what listbatch looks like

```
[[0, 'Rep Entered', '8cfc12c9-000d3a8fc913'],
 [0, 'Rep Entered', '699831ad-0fa60249f33e']]
```

looking a data types, they seem to match:

For listbatch:

```
TEST_IND               int64
SOURCE_LABEL           object
OPPORTUNITYID          object
dtype: object
```

For mytableinTeradata:

```
TEST_IND                        I 
SOURCE_LABEL                    CV
OPPORTUNITYID                   CV
```

I have been able to use this same code before in a different project with no problems. I am not sure what is different here. Any thoughts on what that error means and how to resolve it?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the ? parameter markers in the SQL statement.

Comment: @Fred, thank you, that did it.